# Update TTL in existing Route53 Resource Record set

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have few A records in my Route53 Account. I want to bulk update the TTL for all of them.

The logic I'm using is that I get all the records using "ListResourceRecordSets" operation. Create following change object for each record.

```
array(
    'Action' => 'UPSERT',
    'ResourceRecordSet' => array(
        'Name' => OLD_CNAME,
        'Type' => 'A',
        'TTL' => NEW_TTL,
        'ResourceRecords' => array(array(
                'Value' => OLD_IP
            )),
));
```

Then I send a "ChangeResourceRecordSets" request with change objects created in last step.

Route53 is returning this error **Validation errors: [ChangeBatch][Changes][0][Change][Action] must be one of "CREATE" or "DELETE" [ChangeBatch][Changes][1][Change][Action] must be one of "CREATE" or "DELETE" )**

P.S. I couldn't find any UPSERT example for **ChangeResourceRecordSets** call.

Answer (score 2):

Either update your AWS SDK to a later version that supports UPSERT or You first have to delete the record set(s) and then add them with the new changes.

UPSERT was added in early 2014: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-features-for-route-53-improved-health-checks-https-record-modification/
So you must have a really old SDK.

To do it without UPSERT:

```
array(
'Action' => 'DELETE',
'ResourceRecordSet' => array(
    'Name' => OLD_CNAME,
    'Type' => 'A',
    'TTL' => OLD_TTL,
    'ResourceRecords' => array(array(
            'Value' => OLD_IP
        )),
));
```

and then:

```
array(
'Action' => 'CREATE',
'ResourceRecordSet' => array(
    'Name' => OLD_CNAME,
    'Type' => 'A',
    'TTL' => NEW_TTL,
    'ResourceRecords' => array(array(
            'Value' => OLD_IP
        )),
));
```